# How to print the key which comes before the matching key in python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following json file

```
 {              
    "joseph":[
        {
            "id": "5983",
            "color": "green",
            "material": [ "wood" ],
        },
        {
            "id": "6983",
            "color": "red",
            "material": [ "Aluminum" ],
        },
        {
            "id": "5723",
            "color": "green",
            "material": [ "Iron" ],
        }
    ]
}
```

which I have converted to a python dictionary using the following code

```
import json
def p():
    # Opening JSON file
    with open('filed.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
      
        # for reading nested data [0] represents
        # the index value of the list
        
        # for printing the key-value pair of
        # nested dictionary for looop can be used
        print("\nPrinting nested dicitonary as a key-value pair\n")
        for i in data['joseph']:
            print("Name:", i["material"])
```

Now what I want to do is to print the value of the key "id" which is behind the key "material" that has the value wood, how do I do this?

Comment: You mean the `id` in the same dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` operator to test if a value is in a list. Then print the other key of the same dictionary.

```
for i in data['joseph']:
    if 'wood' in i['material']:
        print("Name:", i['id'])
```

Comment: Right thanks, can you re check the thing, I modified the i["wood"] and turned it to i['material']

Comment: @AmirTheDev What do you mean, his solution gives the results (BTW, that isn't valid json - there shouldn't be a comma after the last entry in each dictionary).

Comment: @ChrisCharley Look at the edit history of my answer. It had a comment about a mistake he had in the code.

Comment: His original code had `print("Name:", i['wood'])`. That part of my answer was referring to that. His comment was pointing out that he fixed the typo.

Comment: The comma in the JSON is almost certainly just because he only posted an excerpt, it's not the real thing.